# Помогите разобратся Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode

Tags: javascript, php

Есть такой код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function call(){
        var msg   = $('#formx').serialize();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'handler.php',
          data: msg,
          //dataType: 'json',
          cache: false,
          beforeSend: function(){
            $('#formx input[type="submit"]').prop("disabled", true).val('Генерируем..');
          },
          success: function(data){
            $('#formx input[type="submit"]').prop("disabled", false).val('Генерировать');
            $('#results .img img').attr('src', data.thumb);
            $('#results .name a').text(data.title);
            $('#results .name a').attr('href', data.url);
            $('#results #duration').text(data.duration);
            $('#results #view').text(data.view);
            $('#results #comment').text(data.comment);
            
            $('#results .avtr img').attr('src', data.win.avatar);
            $('#results .fullname a').attr('href', data.win.link);
            $('#results .fullname a').text(data.win.name);
            $('#results .text').html(data.win.text);
            
            $('#results').show();
            
            bindEvents();
          },
          error:  function(xhr, str){
            alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
          }
        });
    }

</script>
```

При нажатии кнопки, выдает в браузере: Возникла ошибка: undefined

Comment: отдебажь код на сервере и посмотри почему он возвращает error

Comment: Добавь в вопрос точный полный текст ошибки (скопировав его, и вставив). Отредактировать вопрос можно нажав текстовую ссылку "[Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1299351/edit)" под ним.

Comment: А, в вопросе речь о выводе ошибки _алертом_ (сначала я неправильно это понял, подумав про консоль)... Отсутствие свойства `responseCode` вполне нормально, если это `xhr` это экземпляр `XMLHttpRequest`... в таком случае, код ответа сервера - в другом свойстве: **`status`**. То есть, `alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.status);`